# Windows 10 Pro - time freeze

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, command-line, ssd, freeze

I have a problem with my Laptop.

I have a Samsung laptop with 3rd gen i7 QM cpu + 8GB ram + 240GB SSD
with a virus. I can't delete the virus because the virus has frozen my system

- I can't access safe mode
- I can't install new Windows, format is not working with all partition s
- Formatting completed, but after updating the old files return and the new files cannot be saved because there is protection on the SSD. You cancel any external operation
- diskpart is not working.  I don't have permission to the system partition with 100MB.
- I can turn on the computer normally and then uninstall all programs and delete all files. When I turn on the computer again, all the files come back.

So how can I resolve this problem?

Comment: hello any solution ????,,,

Comment: It's probably not "frozen" or a virus. If nothing can write to the SSD then chances are the SSD has failed.

Comment: no , i know this virus injected to the boot and system files . i can see the change to C:/ Driver with injected date .
cuz in same day i download software from youtube with virus . after installation . the virus close any change on my laptop . and disable safe mode with restore point .